# Need show posts in order by selected terms

Tags: php, wordpress

**I need show posts in order by selected terms**

Example:

```
'taxanomy' = 'My_Taxanomy',
'terms' = array(1,2,3),
```

So, FIRST I want show all posts with term 1, then all with term 2, .... Of course all posts in one list.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pages = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => array(1,2,3) // Where term_id of Term 1 is "1".
      'include_children' => false
    )
  )
));
```

Try with this

It can be like this as well

```
$terms = get_terms('taxonomy-name');
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy-name',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term->slug
                )
            ),
            'numberposts' => -1
        ));
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        // do what you want here
    }
}
```

Comment: always bad order. First posts are with term ID 2. I don't understand why